# Unable to update the version of node using nodist in windows 10

Tags: node.js, nodist

I'm trying to update the version of node.js using *nodist 0.9.1*.
When I hit the following command, it installs provided version of node.

```
node 10.14.0
```

Now, when I hit `nodist`, it shows

```
PS C:\Users\Mohit.Sharma> nodist
  (x64)
  10.14.0
  10.16.0
> 11.13.0  (global: v11.13.0)
```

but when I hit `node -v`, it shows

```
v10.7.0
```

Comment: use https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm , it is better

Comment: it could be, but **it is not for windows** and it will not ever be probably. there's https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows **BUT** it is a totally different, while namesake, software.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you might have already installed node on your machine before you install nodist. Try uninstalling node in your control panel. It worked for me.